# How to match two non-consecutive words in a String for React/Javascript search?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, search, next.js

I have a search bar which relies on this filter method.
I concatenate all the search strings in a variable `concat`, and then use either `.includes()` or `.match()` as shown below. If searched for multiple words, this only returns a result if the words occur consecutively in `concat`.

However, I want it to match ANY two words in `concat`, not just consecutive ones. Is there a way to do this easily?

```js
    .filter((frontMatter) => {
      var concat =
        frontMatter.summary +
        frontMatter.title +
        frontMatter.abc+
        frontMatter.def+
        frontMatter.ghi+
        frontMatter.jkl;
      return concat.toLowerCase().match(searchValue.toLowerCase());
    });
```

Also tried;

```js
    .filter((frontMatter) => {
      const concat =
        frontMatter.summary +
        frontMatter.title +
        frontMatter.abc+
        frontMatter.def+
        frontMatter.ghi+
        frontMatter.jkl;
      return concat.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you want something like make a variable, set it to true, do a forEach for `searchValue.toLowerCase().split(" ")`, and each time check if it includes it, and if it doesnt, the variable gets set to false, and then after the forEach just return the variable?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to concatenate all of those front matter parts with a space or something? Currently it's just mashing them together, like if `title = "Hello there"`, `abc = "abc"`, and `def = "def"`... `concat` is `"Hello thereabcdef"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is explained in the comments of the code.

#### If you don't care that "deter" matches the word "undetermined"

```js
.filter((frontMatter) => {
  // Get the front matter into a string, separated by spaces
  const concat = Object.values(frontMatter).join(" ").toLowerCase();

  // Look for a string in quotes, if not then just find a word
  const regex = /\"([\w\s\\\-]+)\"|([\w\\\-]+)/g;

  // Get all the queries
  const queries = [...searchValue.toLowerCase().matchAll(regex)].map((arr) => arr[1] || arr[2]);

  // Make sure that every query is satisfied
  return queries.every((q) => concat.includes(q));
});
```

#### If you DO care that "deter" should NOT match the word "undetermined"

```js
.filter((frontMatter) => {
  // Get the front matter into a string, separated by spaces
  // The prepended and appended spaces are important for the regex later!
  const concat = ` ${Object.values(frontMatter).join(" ").toLowerCase()} `;

  // Look for a string in quotes, if not then just find a word
  const regex = /\"([\w\s\\\-]+)\"|([\w\\\-]+)/g;

  // Get all the queries
  const queries = [...searchValue.toLowerCase().matchAll(regex)].map((arr) => arr[1] || arr[2]);

  // Make sure that every query is satisfied
  // [\\s\\.?!_] and [\\s\\.?!_] check for a space or punctuation at the beginning and end of a word
  // so that something like "deter" isn't matching inside of "undetermined"
  return queries.every((q) => new RegExp(`[\\s\\.?!_]${q}[\\s\\.?!_]`).test(concat));
});
```

Comment: Oh no problem. Sorry for the trouble. This worked. Amazing answer. How about the " " at the end of each value, like you mentioned in the question comment. Is that needed?

Comment: Updated. It is needed, because, say for example, you were searching for `"carpet". If one value ended in `"car"`, and the next one started with `"pet"`, you would find `"carpet"` where you shouldn't since carpet was never a word by itself. (Btw, if this is working for you, please click the gray/green checkmark by the upvote/downvote section to mark this as the correct solution)

Comment: I used your updated solution. There may be something wrong. For a particular search string, I was using in the earlier code, I got 56 results (which was the right number), but for the same search string now I only get 32 results. Even though by the logic in the solution, I should see the number increase because it matches more words now, not decrease. I am confused.

Comment: This returns `true` if all of the words from the search show up in the front matter, and false if there are any words that don't match. Did you want something different?

Comment: Yes, I want any word in the searchValue to match with any in `frontMatter.xyz`. For example, searching for ABC DEF should return all frontMatter posts containing ABC and DEF or ABC and DEF together. Also, I count the number of matches by doing sth like 'frontMatter.length`.

Comment: Oh, so you want it if ANY of the words match? not ALL of the words matching?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @Zac1 This has been updated, let me know if it works now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225446/discussion-between-zac1-and-samathingamajig).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `.reduce` to count up the number of matches, and return true if there are at least 2:

```
const props = ['summary', 'title', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'];
// ...
.filter((frontMatter) => {
  const lowerSearch = searchValue.toLowerCase();
  const matchCount = props.reduce(
    (a, prop) => a + lowerSearch.includes(frontMatter[prop].toLowerCase()),
    0
  );
  return matchCount >= 2;
})
```

Comment: Instead of defining `concat` as a string with `const concat =
        frontMatter.summary +
        frontMatter.title +` etc, define an array of properties and then iterate over them. In my answer, you won't be using a `concat` string at all.

Comment: You did not define the props like I did in the answer. Use exactly `const props = ['summary', 'title', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'];`. If you do `const props = [ frontMatter.summary, frontMatter.title,` etc, you'll have an array of *values* in the `frontMatter` object, not an array of *properties* that exist on the `frontMatter` object.

Comment: If you want to iterate over *all* properties in the object, you could also use `Object.values` instead of hard-coding the properties.

Comment: @CertainPerformance This is checking if the value of each property is inside of `lowerSearch`. This should be the other way around, where you check for each word in `lowerSearch` and see if it's in any of the properties, and multiple words from `lowerSearch` could be in each property, so this looks like the wrong approach altogether